# Event click radio button JQuery in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, radio-button, sharepoint-2013

I want to hide a Sharepoint field based on radio button value. When i put my code, this doesn't work (the event on click doesn't trigger). If i don't put the code with the event, when i open my element the script works perfectly.

This is my code:

```
<p> 
   <script src="/sites/contsvil/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
              $("input[name$='Richiesta 1']").click(function(){

                  var radio_value = $(this).val();
                  alert(radio_value);

             });      
            var selectedValue = $("input[@name=Richiesta 1]:checked");
            //alert(selectedValue.val())              
            if(selectedValue.val() == "No") {                  
                $("input[Title='" + 'Data 1' + "']").closest('td.ms-formbody').closest("tr").hide();
             }else {
                $("input[Title='" + 'Data 1' + "']").closest('td.ms-formbody').closest("tr").show();

             }

        });
    </script></p>
```

Could you help me?

Thank you very much.

Regards,
Francesco

Comment: How does the `html` look like..? is it dynamically generated?

Comment: I've a web application in Sharepoint 2013. I put inside an Editor web Part and put in my code!

Comment: How do we know what's wrong with the script without seeing the html?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting radio buttons isn't as easy as other types on inputs on SharePoint. The following chunk of code gets all the radio buttons on a SharePoint New / Edit page and prints the label to the console.

```
$(":radio").each(function() {
    var radioId = $(this).attr("id");
    var lblText = $("label[for=\""+radioId+"\"]").text();
    console.log(lblText);
});
```

Here is an example of attaching a click event to each radio button:

```
$(":radio").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

This should get you close enough to move forward. For others who wish to jump in, here is the rendered HTML for a radio input on SharePoint (ugly!):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #1"><input id="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a$ctl00$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00">Enter Choice #1</label></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #2"><input id="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a$ctl00$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01"><label for="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01">Enter Choice #2</label></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #3"><input id="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02" type="radio" name="ctl00$m$g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a$ctl00$ctl05$ctl01$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl02"><label for="ctl00_m_g_6ccb25d5_91e9_45b3_bc48_b53a94f40a9a_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02">Enter Choice #3</label></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$("td[id='tdApproved'] input:radio[name*='ff4']").change(function(){
 // do something});
```

"tdApproved" is the ID of the Radio button

For more information, read this article - [Accessing Radio Buttons using JQuery in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2016/10/accessing-radio-buttons-using-jquery-in.html)